# Cannot delete temporary file after File.Copy in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file-access

After copying a file to a temporary directory, I am unable to delete the copy because of an [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx) exception.  The idea here is to get a copy of the file, zip it and then delete the copy, but after removing all the code between [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx)  and [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) I am still getting the exception.  Exiting from the program frees the lock and allows me to delete the copy without issue.

Is there a way to copy without causing this persistent lock (and preserve file metadata like LastModified)?  Or a way to release the lock?  Should there even be a lock on the copied file after `File.Copy` finishes?

I am using Visual C# 2010 SP1 targeting .NET Framework 4.0.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String FileName = "C:\\test.txt";
            // Generate temporary directory name
            String directory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
            // Temporary file path
            String tempfile = Path.Combine(directory, Path.GetFileName(FileName));
            // Create directory in file system
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            // Copy input file to the temporary directory
            File.Copy(FileName, tempfile);
            // Delete file in temporary directory
            File.Delete(tempfile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Run VS 2010 as Administrator

Comment: Is it possible that you do not close tempFile in `Other operations performed`

Comment: @JibranKhan running as administrator doesn't help.

Comment: @I4V that's the thing.  I removed all "other operations performed".  There is no other code between File.Copy and File.Delete.

Comment: What is hidden beneath "Other operations performed" ?

Comment: @jveazey Just ran this code in Linqpad. Ran smoothly

Comment: Have you read the Remarks on the page of `UnauthorizedAccessException`? `The reasons for the exception can be found in the details of the exception object`

Comment: Sorry.  There is no code between the copy and delete.  The "other operations performed" comment line shouldn't have been there. I have removed it.

Comment: How fat is test.txt ?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough access rights on a file in the root of your C:\ drive?

Comment: @Yeronimo The file copies fine.  And I can delete the copy after I kill the debugger.

Comment: Can you also delete the `C:\test.txt` file?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici There are no problems with the source file.  The problem is deleting the copy.

Comment: [File.Copy Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx): _The attributes of the original file are retained in the copied file._ So, if you can't delete the file in `C:\`, you will not be able to delete it anywhere using the same account.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Thank you. That was it. The file was marked as readonly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your  `"C:\\test.txt"` file for read only or not.

based on your comments this may be the reason you can copy but you can't delete

try with below

```
File.SetAttributes(tempfile, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(tempfile);
```

Comment: How come that " Exiting from the program frees the lock and allows me to delete the copy without issue." ?

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already found an answer, but I'll add this for reference anyway; A possible alternative approach for you, might be to create the copy in a memory stream instead of copying the file to your hard-drive.

Using the [DotNetZip library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), you could do something like this:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AddEntry(fileName, data);
        zip.Save(ms);
    }
}
```